# Which of these is grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

"Stop smoking until it's too late"
                       Or
"Stop smoking before it's too late"

Comment: What does your dictionary have to say about it?

Comment: I'm not asking it on the general basis, I'm asking it for this situation.

Comment: And words' definitions are not applicable to specific situations?

Comment: Does "No" mean no in this situation?  :-)

Comment: I suppose yeah ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Stop smoking before it's too late.         correct

He won't stop smoking until he's been diagnosed with lung cancer and

it's too late.